# Pull to refresh :Touch when scroll is in progress sets scrollbar to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, iscroll, pull-to-refresh

I am building a cordova app which has pull to refresh functionality. Pull to refresh and other things are working fine. However, when scrolling is in progress and user touches the screen, scroll bar reaches to bottom of page. I tried debugging it but could not reach to the cause. Surprising fact is, this issue is there on the demo of iscroll as well and I wonder no one has noticed it till now.

iscoll demo link : http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/

if you tap/touch the screen when scrolling is in progress, it goes to bottom of page. Ideally it should stop scrolling. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of head banging, I found a solution. Remove "useTransition: true" from myscroll object and it will be fixed.